# Android File Chooser Absolute Path Issue

Tags: android, android-intent, absolute-path, filechooser

I use the intent filter to get the path of the file selected by the user with a file-chooser,
unfortunately I have problem to obtain the absolute path,

the path onActivityResult starts always with various extra data that cause errors in my app

for example

```
/content/:/myabsolutepath
```

or

```
file:///myabsolutepath
```

and the extra attributes depends on file type, file manager on the phone etc.

I need to get only the absolute path in the form

```
/myabsolutepath
```

Here there is my code

```
private void openFile() {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.setType("file/*");
        startActivityForResult(i, FILE_REQ_CODE);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent i) {
        //String with the path;
        path = i.getDataString();


        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, i);

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```java
path = i.getData().getPath();
```

Comment: This is the right answer, it should be selected as accepted answer.

Comment: That's not absolutube path.